# Impact of the noise distribution on Geometric Brownian motion

Tags: statistical-mechanics, brownian-motion

I have a problem which includes [geometric Brownian motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion), with either normally distributed or power-law-distributed noise, and I'm asking for some explanations about this topic.

Specifically, the questions I would like to be answered are:

1. What are the requirements on the noise distribution for the solution to be a log-normal.
2. What happens if the noise is power-law?

Comment: Is this a physics question?

Comment: @user1504 the two nearly related (the small scale spectrum depends on the stochastic forcing, sometimes cooled noise, indeed, when modelling stochastically driven Navier-Stokes turbulence for example) physics questions are in the second paragraph of this post. These are legitimate questions and I think asking for something to read along with the physics question does not invalidate this question. If I were not preparing for traveling to a conference, I could maybe even answer it...

Comment: @Dilaton  I haven't voted to close, but all I see here is a math question.  You bring up Navier-Stokes, but the OP might have been thinking about stock prices or the swimming habits of sharks.  He doesn't say.

Comment: If this relaxes the readers, this comes from a non-hyperbolic system. I asked here because I don't want neither finance literature nor mathematical theorems... I want physics' literature.

Comment: Hi J. C. Leitão, book recommendation (title) questions are _off-topic._ If you (or someone else?) could edit the question to ask an actual conceptional (title) question I would be happy to consider re-opening the question.